# Invalid access at address: 0 for Mongo v4.0.5

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I am running mongo on Kubernetes in StatefulSets.  It was working fine for weeks then all of a sudden this morning I started getting errors where mongodb was failing.

I tried running:

```
mongod --repair --dbpath /database/db --storageEngine wiredTiger
```

but this did not seem to do anything because it would crash with the below logs.  Any idea how to resolve this?

```
2019-01-02T17:00:50.573+0000 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index on: tekdash.User properties: { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "tekdash.User" }
2019-01-02T17:00:50.573+0000 I INDEX    [initandlisten]      building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 500 megabytes of RAM
2019-01-02T17:00:50.753+0000 W ASIO     [initandlisten] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
2019-01-02T17:00:50.753+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Invalid access at address: 0
2019-01-02T17:00:50.771+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault).
 0x55b4eb4a72e1 0x55b4eb4a64f9 0x55b4eb4a6b66 0x7efd76044390 0x55b4eaceafbc 0x55b4eacd9e31 0x55b4eacde5f7 0x55b4eacde781 0x55b4e9eb32c7 0x55b4eade4528 0x55b4ea9fca1b 0x55b4ea339bdb 0x55b4e9fba78f 0x55b4e9fc0b8a 0x55b4e9a53437 0x55b4e9b3b97b 0x55b4e9ad15a9 0x7efd75c89830 0x55b4e9b39ae9
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"55B4E90BC000","o":"23EB2E1","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"55B4E90BC000","o":"23EA4F9"},{"b":"55B4E90BC000","o":"23EAB66"},{"b":"7EFD76033000","o":"11390"},{"b":"55B4E90BC000","o":"1C2EFBC","s":"_ZN5mongo8executor18NetworkInterfaceTL8shutdownEv"},{"b":"55B4E90BC000","o":"1C1DE31","s":"_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutor5_joinESt11unique_lockISt5mutexE"},{"b":"55B4E90BC000","o":"1C225F7","s":"_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutorD1Ev"},{"b":"55B4E90BC000","o":"1C22781","s":"_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutorD0Ev"},{"b":"55B4E90BC000","o":"DF72C7"},{"b":"55B4E90BC000","o":"1D28528","s":"_ZN5mongo23CollectionShardingState3getEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_15NamespaceStringE"},{"b":"55B4E90BC000","o":"1940A1B","s":"_ZN5mongo31AutoGetCollectionForReadCommandC1EPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_21NamespaceStringOrUUIDENS_17AutoGetCollection8ViewModeENS_6Date_tE"},{"b":"55B4E90BC000","o":"127DBDB","s":"_ZN5mongo7Helpers12getSingletonEPNS_16OperationContextEPKcRNS_7BSONObjE"},{"b":"55B4E90BC000","o":"EFE78F"},{"b":"55B4E90BC000","o":"F04B8A","s":"_ZN5mongo30repairDatabasesAndCheckVersionEPNS_16OperationContextE"},{"b":"55B4E90BC000","o":"997437"},{"b":"55B4E90BC000","o":"A7F97B","s":"_ZN5mongo11mongoDbMainEiPPcS1_"},{"b":"55B4E90BC000","o":"A155A9","s":"main"},{"b":"7EFD75C69000","o":"20830","s":"__libc_start_main"},{"b":"55B4E90BC000","o":"A7DAE9","s":"_start"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "4.0.5", "gitVersion" : "3739429dd92b92d1b0ab120911a23d50bf03c412", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.15.0-1030-azure", "version" : "#31~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 30 19:40:01 UTC 2018", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "b" : "55B4E90BC000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D2BD849936E6F1CDEAA6678F57E07D725B522378" }, { "b" : "7FFD4ADFC000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "EB4266DE01729239D0A2A1F10C5AF3A733C81B52" }, { "b" : "7EFD77444000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E2D1DB1857AE8F07908959381751796E89FF56BB" }, { "b" : "7EFD77229000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "6EF73266978476EF9F2FD2CF31E57F4597CB74F8" }, { "b" : "7EFD76DE4000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8942CA58A3B910E883CC31E04A23DBD09729B4B0" }, { "b" : "7EFD76B7B000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "473092A9AF373FB0CAB555F9A003BC67F47756B6" }, { "b" : "7EFD76977000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8CC8D0D119B142D839800BFF71FB71E73AEA7BD4" }, { "b" : "7EFD7676F000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "89C34D7A182387D76D5CDA1F7718F5D58824DFB3" }, { "b" : "7EFD76466000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DFB85DE42DAFFD09640C8FE377D572DE3E168920" }, { "b" : "7EFD76250000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "68220AE2C65D65C1B6AAA12FA6765A6EC2F5F434" }, { "b" : "7EFD76033000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "CE17E023542265FC11D9BC8F534BB4F070493D30" }, { "b" : "7EFD75C69000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B5381A457906D279073822A5CEB24C4BFEF94DDB" }, { "b" : "7EFD776B3000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "5D7B6259552275A3C17BD4C3FD05F5A6BF40CAA5" }, { "b" : "7EFD75A36000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E09D3783AD1D0BBCD3204FA01E4EF6D756E18F57" }, { "b" : "7EFD7581A000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8D1CC1204D6B6D33BD1D2C5A2A0516A2234322CF" }, { "b" : "7EFD755D0000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DB5180B568097E2A4690A5B40D36BD134C893FEE" }, { "b" : "7EFD753C1000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "5B146086EC173C299BA45F0C92E068D68CC7AD37" }, { "b" : "7EFD75170000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D02A94DB90567C2C45F40C8565809A041FD22A55" }, { "b" : "7EFD74F56000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8D9BD4CE26E45EF16075C67D5F5EEAFD8B562832" }, { "b" : "7EFD74C26000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "3CE893F6D1382C2C7648DCCB06E71B1C7E0861CC" }, { "b" : "7EFD749F3000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B11678F560199547DCF726384EA39153EE0DFABF" }, { "b" : "7EFD747BD000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D6B36C5A463EE0FA84FDD6D5FD3F7726EDB90D54" }, { "b" : "7EFD7453D000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7B3533D5998D20EE1A1BE3F87789B69041E7F620" }, { "b" : "7EFD7426B000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "16E3DBC6D048145939BB43BBFD7954D27421B00F" }, { "b" : "7EFD7403C000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "AEB4C08FC47F86C475E9D3996DFE5E9B403ACEBF" }, { "b" : "7EFD73E38000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1E16CB57F699E215A2A8D4EFEF90883BC749B12D" }, { "b" : "7EFD73C2D000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DF3219B89E86920E901BAC4A80AA60F2B6134588" }, { "b" : "7EFD73A12000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "87783DF8A1058CD150F8886CB36340384093C18F" }, { "b" : "7EFD737D1000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1FE877BE52A424D0636AFD4D35BB330E41D6E0F3" }, { "b" : "7EFD7356D000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A0E2D03FF5CF65937F4425D4EFD4D655243809EB" }, { "b" : "7EFD7335A000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E07E186694852D8F69459C6AB28A53F8DA3CE3B6" }, { "b" : "7EFD73156000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "3364D4BF2113C4E8D17EF533867ECC99A53413D6" }, { "b" : "7EFD72F4D000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "73A8EADBC85860662B24850E71D4AFBE22C33359" }, { "b" : "7EFD72CC3000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "59E742306A4EA2872E061ECCE92F35FADDA75357" }, { "b" : "7EFD72A21000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E5C159E415406AE79D21056D752BA949C408B5B1" }, { "b" : "7EFD727EE000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7D15576E1F096614D360784E4A01A1F5FAF908C9" }, { "b" : "7EFD725D8000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "481DB33C28D88E43DA6BED65E1A7599407D4D818" }, { "b" : "7EFD723D0000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9D9C958F1F4894AFEF6AECD90D1C430EA29AC34F" }, { "b" : "7EFD721A7000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "57E25072866B2D30CF02EBE7AE623B84F96FA700" }, { "b" : "7EFD71F98000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F6F1B4E9F89B716C4A0BA5819BDFFAF4A13EFB91" }, { "b" : "7EFD71D4D000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C60082E3BB78D0D42868D9B359B89BF66CE5A1A7" }, { "b" : "7EFD71A78000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D9782BA023CAEC26B15D8676E3A5D07B55E121EF" }, { "b" : "7EFD71840000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7BDD51353D50310FFA1587E4AA01B40ABE32D582" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x41) [0x55b4eb4a72e1]
 mongod(+0x23EA4F9) [0x55b4eb4a64f9]
 mongod(+0x23EAB66) [0x55b4eb4a6b66]
 libpthread.so.0(+0x11390) [0x7efd76044390]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8executor18NetworkInterfaceTL8shutdownEv+0xDC) [0x55b4eaceafbc]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutor5_joinESt11unique_lockISt5mutexE+0x421) [0x55b4eacd9e31]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutorD1Ev+0x67) [0x55b4eacde5f7]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo8executor22ThreadPoolTaskExecutorD0Ev+0x11) [0x55b4eacde781]
 mongod(+0xDF72C7) [0x55b4e9eb32c7]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo23CollectionShardingState3getEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_15NamespaceStringE+0x98) [0x55b4eade4528]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo31AutoGetCollectionForReadCommandC1EPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_21NamespaceStringOrUUIDENS_17AutoGetCollection8ViewModeENS_6Date_tE+0xBB) [0x55b4ea9fca1b]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo7Helpers12getSingletonEPNS_16OperationContextEPKcRNS_7BSONObjE+0x11B) [0x55b4ea339bdb]
 mongod(+0xEFE78F) [0x55b4e9fba78f]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo30repairDatabasesAndCheckVersionEPNS_16OperationContextE+0x5EA) [0x55b4e9fc0b8a]
 mongod(+0x997437) [0x55b4e9a53437]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo11mongoDbMainEiPPcS1_+0x10DB) [0x55b4e9b3b97b]
 mongod(main+0x9) [0x55b4e9ad15a9]
 libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xF0) [0x7efd75c89830]
 mongod(_start+0x29) [0x55b4e9b39ae9]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? you only specified the errors for the repair command.